# Registrar hora en android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-sqlite

Estoy haciendo una Aplicacion de scanner Qr, ya tengo codificado el scanner lo que quiero hacer es que al momento de scannear un codigo, me registre la hora actual automaticamente en la que fue hecho el scanner, uso sq lite para registrar datos, si alguien me pudiera ayudar se lo agradeceria mucho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una forma de obtener la fecha es con `SimpleDateFormat`, el formato lo recoges acorde al que tengas en tu campo de la base de datos (`date` o `datetime`).

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
String currentDateandTime = simpleDateFormat.format(new Date());
```